# How do I use Apache http to proxy to two different tomcat servers?

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy

I have apache httpd that I want to proxy to two different tomcat servers.

I see this:
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/proxy.html

But that is only for one tomcat server. What if I had one server running on 8081 in addition to a tomcat running at 8080?

Comment: How do you want this to proxy? You want one location to be proxied to multiple destinations like a load balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache httpd two out-of-the-box options for proxying to any number of backend Tomcat instances:

1. `mod_proxy_http`
2. `mod_proxy_ajp`

They are configured identically to each other, except that the former uses the HTTP protocol for communication and the latter uses the AJP protocol and URLs that start with `ajp://` instead of `http://` for the backend server. Both can be configured for load-balancing, failover, etc. in the same way. You can proxy to completely separate Tomcat instances (i.e. no load-balancing: just separate backends) by providing separate proxy configuration for separate URL spaces (e.g. `/app1` -> Tomcat1  and `/app2` -> Tomcat2) or you can configure the two (or more) backend instances for load-balancing, etc.

Specifically, look at the documentation for the following httpd configuration directives:

```
<Proxy>
BalanceMember
ProxyPass
ProxyPassReverse
```

You can find documentation for all of these here:

1. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html (General)
2. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html (HTTP)
3. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html (AJP)
4. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html (load-balancer)

If you want to use the AJP protocol and you have more complex configuration needs, you can also use `mod_jk` (*not* `mod_jk2`, which is an old, dead, abandoned, completely irrelevant project, now). You can find out more about `mod_jk` on the Tomcat site here: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/

`mod_jk` has a radically different configuration procedure and a lot more AJP-specific options than `mod_proxy_ajp`.

The (short) documentation you mentioned in your original post (from the old `mod_jk2` docs) points to Apache httpd's `mod_proxy_ajp` and `mod_proxy_balancer` modules (though it points to the unstable httpd 2.1, which was the bleeding-edge at the time that documentation was written). You were on the right track: you just needed to keep reading. You can definitely proxy to as many backend instances of Tomcat as you want with any of the modules described here.

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way to setup load balancing using [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html). Simply list the tomcat servers under a balancer list than put that balancer in your `ProxyPass`:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://tomcat1:8080/
    BalancerMember http://tomcat2:8081/
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /test balancer://mycluster
```

Comment: Yes you're right apache's mod_proxy is also one of the way of doing this. Only I am not sure about it's implementation on high traffic websites but for low to moderate this should be okay.

@Jon: I tried using it once but later on switched to haproxy - are you using it on production for some implementation?

Comment: @Dharmavir Not in production and not in any significant scale. But OP wants to proxy to 2 tomcat instances, running on the same server, it doesn't seem like there's any need for serious load balancing.

Comment: Load Balancer will not do the job if you want to pass same requests to several backends at the same time. Basically apache mod_proxy will not do the job, unless author is asking for load balance traffic. (mistake vote this answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can install HAProxy on either 3rd server which will work as LB to both of them or you can install HAProxy on any one of them and then do following configuration.

To install HAProxy (if you're running Ubuntu/Debain distro)

```
  $ sudo apt-get install haproxy
  # Setup config file in /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cnf per requirement
  # change /etc/default/ to Enabled = 1 and restart haproxy service
```

after setup do following mods in config:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

global
        maxconn 4096
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option  redispatch
        maxconn 2000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

listen webcluster *:80
        mode    http
        stats   enable
        stats   auth us3r:passw0rd
        balance roundrobin
        option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.0
        option forwardfor
        cookie LSW_WEB insert
        option httpclose
        server web01 192.168.0.1:8080 cookie LSW_WEB01 check
        server web02 192.168.0.2:8081 cookie LSW_WEB02 check
```

Once done, restart HAProxy service by:

```
$ sudo service haproxy restart
```

Here 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2 can be your two servers one can be running on port 8080 and another can be on 8081.

Ref. Post: http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2011/07/high-availability-load-balancing-using-haproxy-on-ubuntu-part-1/
You will also find online help if you will google about how to setup haproxy on your linux distribution if you're not using Ubuntu/Debain. But yes you can bet on it as it's proven tool for the job.